`pyenv versions` Not showing my previously installed python version on Windows
I had python version 3.11.5 installed on Windows 11.
Then I installed pyenv to manage python versions.
But then the pyenv versions was not showing the previously installed python version.
I installed python 3.9.5 using the cmd:
pyenv install 3.9.5
It installed correctly.
Then I wanted to see the versions of python installed, I did:
python -V
I got: Python 3.11.5.
Then I did:
pyenv versions
I got: 3.9.5
(Pl see the image: https://i.sstatic.net/ht0IS.png)
Why is pyenv versions not showing the python version which was installed previously on my Windows 11?
pyenv not showing the previously installed python versions
